# React Routing: How to make selected nav item as Active?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to make/show selected nav item as active.I check regarding questions but i cant find whats wrong in my code.

I know by using ***NavLink*** ,we can make by default active when select the Nav-Item.

But now, i'm trying with ***Link*** , showing some pathname error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

Please help me to know , what's wrong in my code.

Or **Is there any alternatives to show the active nav Item?**

I tried the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import { IndexRoute, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class SideNav extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div className="sidebar-container">
          <ul className="sidebar-menu">
            <li className={location.pathname === "/" && "active"}>
              <Link className="link" to="/">
                <i className="fa fa-cubes icon"></i>
                Dashboard
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className={location.pathname === "/analytics" && "active"}>
              <Link className="link" to="/analytics">
                <i className="fa fa-pie-chart icon"></i>
                Analytics
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className={location.pathname === "/todo" && "active"}>
              <Link className="link" to="/todo">
                <i className="fa fa-medkit icon"></i>
                What to do?
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default SideNav;
```

Routing is working perfectly.

My routing app/component code as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import TopNav from "./components/Navbar/TopNav";
import SideNav from "./components/Navbar/SideNav";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Analytics from "./components/Analytics";
import ToDo from "./components/ToDo";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <SideNav />
        <TopNav />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Dashboard />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/analytics">
            <Analytics />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/todo">
            <ToDo />
          </Route>
          <Redirect to="/"></Redirect>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Thanks!!

Comment: It looks like location is comming undefined, do you have this component inside the router?

Comment: yes. I'll update that code also in question .@CarlosSaizOrteu

Comment: try wrapping ```SideNav``` inside withRouter like: ```export default withRouter(SideNav)```

Comment: withRouter is not defined @saeedghotb

Comment: import it then. ```import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'```

Comment: @saeedghotb ,It works..Thanks, give it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping your component with withRouter should do it.

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

// your component

export default withRouter(SideNav)
```

I really don't know why(!) but in some cases withRouter has failed to set active class and i finally had to modify the routes like this:

```js
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" render={(routeParams)=><Component {...routeParams}/>}/>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Location is a property of history, so you need to use props.history.location instead of props.location
Also you did not pass history object to props, it will not appear there automatically